# Stripe PaymentIntent Key Undefined | Unable to pass ClientSecret key from Controller | Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stripe-payments

Im working on a code to take payments in ASP.net framework MVC application. Without the SCA approach using the old API createtoken() the code is working correctly payment is being generated but I need to add the 3d secure functionality thus the need of PaymentIntent() CreatePaymentIntent.  I am being unable to pass my PI Secret Key it remains undefined. Here is my code

index.cshtml

```
<div class="col-md-6">
            <form>
                <h1 style="color:white"> Payment Details £<span class="faretxt"></span></></h1>

                <label>
                    <h4 class="errormessage alert-danger"></h4>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input class="field is-empty" id="faretxt" value="" type="hidden" />
                    <div id="card-element" class="field is-empty"></div>
                    <span><span>Credit or debit card</span></span>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <h4 class="errormessage alert-danger"></h4>
                </label>
                <div class="outcome">
                    <div class="error" role="alert"></div>
                    <div class="success">
                        Success! Your Stripe token is <span class="token"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button id="btnsubmit" type="button">Pay £<span class="faretxt"></span></button>
            </form>
  </div>
```

Scripts:

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
var stripe = Stripe('######');
    var elements = stripe.elements();

    var card = elements.create('card', {
        iconStyle: 'solid',
        style: {
            base: {
                iconColor: '#8898AA',
                color: 'white',
                lineHeight: '36px',
                fontWeight: 300,
                fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
                fontSize: '19px',

                '::placeholder': {
                    color: '#8898AA',
                },
            },
            invalid: {
                iconColor: '#e85746',
                color: '#e85746',
            }
        },
        classes: {
            focus: 'is-focused',
            empty: 'is-empty',
        },
    });
    card.mount('#card-element');
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input.field');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs, function (input) {

        input.addEventListener('focus', function () {
            input.classList.add('is-focused');
        });
        input.addEventListener('blur', function () {
            input.classList.remove('is-focused');
        });
        input.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
            if (input.value.length === 0) {
                input.classList.add('is-empty');
            } else {
                input.classList.remove('is-empty');
            }
        });
    });

    

    card.on('change', function (event) {
        setOutcome(event);
    });

   // document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    $('#btnsubmit').click(function (e) {
        //e.preventDefault();

        $(this).attr("disabled", true);

        var form = document.querySelector('form');
        var extraDetails = {
            //name: form.querySelector('input[name=cardholder-name]').value,
        };

        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Please Wait ..submit last code.',
            onBeforeOpen() {
                Swal.showLoading()
            },
            onAfterClose() {
                Swal.hideLoading()
            },
            allowOutsideClick: false,
            allowEscapeKey: false,
            allowEnterKey: false,
            showConfirmButton: false,
            showCancelButton: false,
        });
        console.log("Working till here: ") ;

       // stripe.createToken(card, extraDetails).then(setOutcome);
        payWithCard(stripe, card, clientSecret);


       



        var payWithCard = function (stripe, card, clientSecret) {
            debugger
            stripe
                .confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
                    payment_method: {
                        card: card
                    }
                })
                .then(function (result) {
                    if (result.error) {
                        // Show error to your customer
                        showError(result.error.message);
                    } else {
                        // The payment succeeded!
                        orderComplete(result.paymentIntent.id);
                    }
                });
        };
       });
```

HomeController.cs

```
     public ActionResult Create(string clientSecret, string amount, string jobref){
 StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "####";
        Description = "testt"
        double amountcal = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(amount));
     
        var services = new PaymentIntentService();
        var opt = new PaymentIntentCreateOptions
        {
            Amount = long.Parse(amountcal.ToString()) * 100,
            Currency = "GBP",
            Description = description,
        };
        var paymentIntent = services.Create(opt);

        //clientSecret = paymentIntent.clientSecret;
        return Json(new { clientSecret = paymentIntent.ClientSecret });
```

Im being unable to fetchthe clientsecret key. anyhelp would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to replace orderComplete(result.paymentIntent.id); by orderComplete(result.clientSecret);

Answer (score 0):

Right now your javascript code isn't making any attempt to fetch the client secret from your backend endpoint, which is why it's undefined. You need to implement something this:

```
fetch("/create-payment-intent", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(purchase)
})
  .then(function(result) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    // Use data.client_secret to confirm the card payment.
  };
```

You can see a full sample of this in Stripe's integration builder here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/integration-builder

Comment: Hi Karbi,I understood your answer but isnt fetch  is for asp core. is there any simillar method to go with MVC controller

Comment: Fetch is not limited to asp core, you should be fine using it with the asp.net MVC